# Evitar que mi boton recargue toda la pagina

Tags: javascript, html, botón

tengo un botón que lanza un console.log para mostrarme que funciona correctamente, lo que me pasa es que al pulsarlo me sale la alerta que tengo para cuando se cierra o se recarga la pagina, necesito evitar que mi botón me recargue la pagina.

el boton en el index.html

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-GuardarCambios" onclick="pulsar()">
    Guardar Cambios
  </button>
```

funcion del boton en el index.js

```
function pulsar() {
    console.log("Has precionado el boton guardar")
    
}
```

Comment: Pues no veo que el botón en sí recargue la página, algo más has de tener en tu código al cual está respondiendo tu botón.

Comment: Intenta con [event.preventDefault()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) para cancelar el comportamiento normal del botón (¿submit?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tienen que indicar que no quieres que la acción avance hacia el servidor. Esto lo logras retornando un **false** en tu javascript:

Opción 1: onclick="pulsar();return false()

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-GuardarCambios" onclick="pulsar(); return false()">
Guardar Cambios
```

Opción 2: onclick="return pulsar();"

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-GuardarCambios" onclick="return pulsar()">Guardar Cambios</button>
function pulsar() {
console.log("Has precionado el boton guardar")
return false;
```

}